# how can I keep the same height from vertical divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a ranked system tier that it is scaled based on how much points the user has to earn new ranks , but how can I remove the `br`'s and keep the same height as the image expected?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .parent {
        display: table;
    }

    .child {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
</style>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Test
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Test Test Test <br/> Test Test Test
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Test Test Test<br/> Test Test Test<br/> Test Test Test
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Test Test Test<br/> Test Test Test<br/> Test Test Test<br/> Test Test Test
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Test Test Test<br/> Test Test Test<br/> Test Test Test<br/> Test Test Test<br/> Test Test Test
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: system_tier]

Comment: The primary thing to do is wrap each "Test Test Test" or whatever in it's own container. a `p` tag would seem the most appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

With the Flex can you do the same, please refer the below code for same

Use CSS

```
.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}    

.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */

  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}
```

Use HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: basically , I am getting this https://imgur.com/a/h5jdlhx  , but I want to keep the same format as before without `br`

Comment: If you want to give a specific height for the div's then you can use, .parent .child{height: 250px;padding:15px}, you can use your height and padding their, hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

You could set a specific width for child class, I used 90px but this would collapse on small screens though.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .parent {
      display: table;
    }
    
    .child {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding-left: 20px;
      width: 90px;
      text-align:right;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Test
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Test Test Test Test Test Test
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if I remove all `Test` , and I Only write one `Test` , everything is in-line, but how can I keep the same format?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
    Test
</div>
<div class="child">
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
</div>
<div class="child">
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
</div>
<div class="child">
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
</div>
<div class="child">
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
    <div> Test Test Test </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: By replacing all br's and writing your code inside div element keeps the same output as you expect

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .parent {
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
    }

    .child {
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .child p{ margin:0; }
</style>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Test
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
   </div>
 
    <div class="child">
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
        <p>Test Test Test</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```